# How to remove ffmpeg warning "deprecated pixel format used"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been trying for a few days to design a command line that will allow me to convert all video files '.ts' of a directory into '.mp4' files of good quality on which I will have made settings, especially on the contrast, the saturation, the volume ...

So I wrote the command line (which I will integrate later in a loop 'for'):

`ffmpeg.exe -y -report -i "video-1.ts" -vf eq=brightness=-0.08:contrast=0.8:saturation=1.3 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1500k -bt 3000k -r 30 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 1 -filter:a "volume=0.5" -async 1 -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:30.000 "video-1.mp4"`

It works.

But there is something that annoys me and that I can not solve: from the moment I integrate the filter `-vf` where I adjust the brightness, contrast and saturation, I have a warning that appears:

> deprecated pixel format used, make sure you set range correctly...

I do not understand why and I would like to understand to deepen my knowledge about ffmpeg.

I tried everything (well I think): `pix_fmt`, `color_range`, `scale` forced ... I even danced in slip on polka music hoping that it can help ... No. Impossible: I can not delete this warning.

Would someone have the extreme kindness to help me please?

Comment: Some comments: `-b:v 1500k` is not ideal. If you want good quality and efficient file size, use `-crf 21` instead. See [here](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html) for more info. I don't know what `-bt` is – remove it. `-ac 1` should be removed unless you want mono audio? `-async 1` should not be needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.
I replaced -b:v to -crf : it is better :).
I want mono audio, right.
-async : If i don't use it, I have some audio error and some crash in the vidéo